# Tomcat reads wrong evironment variable value

Tags: java, tomcat

I've set up my env var as follows
[image]

But when I start the service I see:

```
05-Apr-2023 15:05:38.441 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Apr-2023 15:05:38.441 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
05-Apr-2023 15:05:38.442 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
05-Apr-2023 15:05:38.442 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
05-Apr-2023 15:05:38.442 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
```

So i looked here:

[image]

I changed it to:

[image]

started again the service:

```
05-Apr-2023 15:41:02.426 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Projects\java_app\instance
05-Apr-2023 15:41:02.427 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
05-Apr-2023 15:41:02.427 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
05-Apr-2023 15:41:02.427 INFORMAZIONI [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Projects\java_app\instance
```

which begs the question... what's the pourpose of the CATALINA_BASE env var?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/introduction.html#Why_Use_CATALINA_BASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about when the environment variable takes effect.

On Windows, environment variables such as `CATAILNA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` are not used by the [service-runner](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) when starting/stopping the service. Instead, those environment variables are *only* used by the `bin/service.bat` script to configure the service, where those values are copied into the `catalina.home` and `catalina.base` Java system properties.

If you want to change the way the service runs, you will need to edit the service using `tomcatXw.exe` and modify those environment variables. You can also delete the service and reinstall/configure it using `bin/service.bat` again.

On Windows, it never makes any sense to set global environment variables to try to control Tomcat, because they are ignored after the service has been defined.